# preg_match_all() into variable for each?

Tags: php

Hi How can I get the echo $row2 into one variabel for each $row2?

There will be 5 matches for $day $row, each one containing 3-6 $ratt as $row2.

How can I get each $ratt[1] to a variable like

```
$day1 = "...|...|...|...|...|...";
$day2 = "...|...|...|...|...|...";
$day3 = "...|...|...|...|...|...";
$day4 = "...|...|...|...|...|...";
$day5 = "...|...|...|...|...|...";


preg_match_all('/<div id=\"lunchmenyspaltrubrik\">(.*)<\/div>.*<ul>(.*)<\/ul>/Us', $contents, $dag, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($day as $row ) {
   preg_match_all('/<div id=\"nyheterspaltbrod\">(.*?)<\/div>/', $row[2], $ratt);
   foreach ($ratt[1] as $row2 ) {
      echo $row2.'<br>';
   }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've accepted any answers to your questions on Stack Overflow. When you get helpful answers to your questions, you should always pick the best one and mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. This will also award you some reputation points! If a better answer comes along later, you are able to switch the accepted answer to that one. If you haven't taken the SO tour, check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry if that's the case. I can't find any comment though from a user m59 in any of my so far 3 "ask:s" ... exept for the one 1 hour ago that I have not looked at yet :) ... or do you have another username as well?

Comment: OK, thanks ... I've accepted them now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend leaving them in an array: **[Live demo (click).](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/afe4408cab97e0e11f4e0be793df14900749ee1d)**

```
$days = [];
foreach ($ratt[1] as $row2 ) {
   $days[] = $row2;
}

var_dump($days[0]);
var_dump($days[1]);
//etc
```

If you really wanted to, you can get them to individual variables using php's variable variables: **[Live demo (click).](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa334bc0c3db3bddab20a3737af68ceea53b2f72)**

```
$myArr = $ratt[1];    

for ($i=0; $i<count($myArr); ++$i) {
  $v = $myArr[$i];
  $varName = 'day'.$i;
  $$varName = $v;
}

var_dump($day0);
var_dump($day1);
//etc
```

If you want them to be numbered starting with `1` rather than `0` (and this is not recommended!) just +1 `$i` when writing the variable name:

```
$varName = 'day'.($i+1);
```

Comment: I tried both your examples and the first one just gives me an error.

The other one gives me th first row2 from every $ratt[1] if I echo $days[0]

Comment: @user3214817 see the demos I included in my updated answer. These solutions work. The problems are with other parts of your code. You should accept my answer and post another question about what you're actually trying to do. This question is "how do I set variables for each item of an array". As I said, that's not a good idea. You're trying to do that because you don't know a better way to achieve your goal. Instead, search for a good approach to your goal (what your program should do). If you can't find a good approach, post another question asking about it.

Comment: @user3214817 In other words, you have an X/Y problem. Read more about this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem This should help you ask about and solve your real problem.